# Passing Multiple Parameters in a form_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I'm using Rails and jqPlot to display some data on a webpage. The graph needs to be flexible by date (as in, the user can select a time range, and the graph will update itself). Here's my code so far (in my View):

```
<%= form_tag home_event_trends_path(params[:timePeriod]), :method => 'post' do %>
  <p>
    <%= select_tag :timePeriod, options_for_select(["2 Hours Ago", "1 Week Ago", "3 Months Ago"], :selected => params[:timePeriod]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Refresh", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

`Home` is my controller, `event_trends` is an action, I suppose. (The path is localhost:3000/home/event_trends.3102030)

This works fine. However, I need to also pass another parameter to my controller. This webpage is already having a parameter passed to it, `params[:format]` (this is the 3102030 in the URL, which changes based upon what event I want to display), and I need this passed along as well.  I've tried:

```
home_event_trends_path(params[:timePeriod][:format])
home_event_trends_path(params[:timePeriod],[:format])
home_event_trends_path(params([:timePeriod][:format]))
```

among others.

How do I get my controller to see multiple parameters from my View?

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding using a params[:format] as this is used by Rails to know what type to render (JSON, JS, XML, HTML ...). Also take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html. This will help you understand how forms work in Rails

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto: I didn't pick :format, that's just what it turned out to be. I don't know how to change that. Also, I've been up and down that page, it's all over my head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing against Idan's answer, but this was what I ended up doing (for future Googlers...)

In my View:

```
<%= form_tag home_event_trends_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= select_tag :timePeriod, options_for_select(["2 Hours Ago", "1 Week Ago", "3 Months Ago"], :selected => params[:timePeriod]) %>
    <%= text_field_tag :issue, params[:issue] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Refresh", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And then in my Home Controller:

```
def event_trends
  @eventTrend = Home.eventTrend(params[:timePeriod], params[:issue])
end
```

And finally, the Model:

```
def self.eventTrend(date, id)
  # dirty work
end
```

This seems to work best for me. I decided to allow the URL to change for the GET request, and I'm immediately storing the `issue` parameter in the search box, for use later on.

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I see you are passing the **old** `timePeriod` using GET and the new `timePeriod` using POST. Is this really what you want? Why does the controller need the old `timePeriod`?

Since you want to display a graph - that is, you want to retrieve data, not to cause side effects - I think you should send only the new `timePeriod` using GET:

```
<%= form_tag home_event_trends_path(), :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        <%= select_tag :timePeriod, options_for_select(["2 Hours Ago", "1 Week Ago", "3 Months Ago"], :selected => params[:timePeriod]) %>
        <%= select_tag :format, options_for_select([...], :selected => params[:format]) %>
        <%= submit_tag "Refresh", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Also, I agree with Anthony - you should try to change the `format` parameter - just look in the controller to see where it is used, and change the name.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by OLD and NEW timePeriod? When the user selects a new option from the dropdown menu and hits 'refresh', the browser sends `timePeriod` to the server-side Rails, at which point it queries my database within the new time range, and returns those entries which fit. I was using POST because I wanted to avoid having the parameters in the URL.

Comment: You are sending `params[:timePeriod]` to `home_event_trends_path` - that means that `params[:timePeriod]` is part of the form's target path. That function is called during the rendering of the HTML page - that means that the HTML form sent to the user already contains that path with `params:[timePeriod]` - and that happens **before** the user picks the time period in the form - hence it is the **old** `timePeriod`.  About the sending method, it's your choice really, but at any rate the easiest way is to send all the parameters as form elements.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I've changed everything to GET after re-working some things. I've also renamed (I think) `:format` to `:issue`. Your code actually created another dropdown for me. This isn't necessary, as the user shouldn't be able to select the issue from the page. I just want the current issue (as defined in the URL) to be passed on as well. Also, I've managed to change the URL so that it is `/home/event_trends?issue=123456`. When I click refresh, this issue parameter is replace with `/home/event_trends?utf8=✓&timePeriod=3+Months+Ago`. I need both still!

Comment: If you don't want the user to select the `issue`(at this form. At some earlier point the user does need to choose it somehow...), you can use the [hidden field tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) to add that parameter as a form element. You can also send it as the form's action path(like you tried to send `timePeriod` in the code example you put in the question), but it tends to create uglier code, and is not really necessary unless you need to mix GET and POST.